# Match key words in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

i have a search function on my website where users can search for products. it works perfectly fine except for the fact that when a user searches for 'ipod' it comes up with no result as the name of the product is 'apple ipod'. how do i code it so that when part of the name of the product is searched, the correct product comes up?

my code is as follows:

```
    <div id="search" align="right">
<form action="" method="get">
  <span id="sprytextfield1">
  <input name="search" id="search2" type="text" width="250px"/>
  <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg"></span></span>
  <input name="" type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form></div>
<br /><br />
<h2>Your Search Results For "<?php echo $_GET['search'] ?>":</h2><hr />

    <table border="0" cellpadding="2px" width="600px">
        <?
        $search = $_GET['search'];

            $result=mysql_query("select * from products WHERE name = '$search'")
            or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
       echo '&nbsp;'.'Could Not Be Found';
    }   
    else {

            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo'<img src="getImage.php?id=' . $row['serial'] .'"/>'
?>            </td>
            <td>    <b><a href="pdaproduct.php?product_id=<?=$row['serial']?>"><?=$row['name']?></a></b><br />
                    Price:<big style="color:green">
                        £<?=$row['price']?></big><br /><br />
                    <input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="addtocart(<?=$row['serial']?>)" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><hr size="1" /></td>

        <? 
            }
    }?>
    </table>
```

thanks for any advice given! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that your code should never be used for production (it's unsafe), you should use a `LIKE` in your query.

```
mysql_query("select * from products WHERE name LIKE '%$search%'")
```

Now, optimized against SQL injections and other things you don't want, this would become:

```
mysql_query("select * from products WHERE name LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search)."%'")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `LIKE` statement, like so

```
select * from products WHERE name LIKE '%$search%'
```

The above will match both 'apple ipod', 'ipod' and 'apple ipod'

Answer (score 0):

Searching keyword in a table (eg: your product list) **LIKE** can be very useful but doesn't perform well on long text fields (eg: description), so consider also full text index and the **MATCH () AGAINST** operator.

Here mysql manual [page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

To avoid to return the page *No results found, sorry*, (after a none results query) you can use the **SOUNDEX** operator

```
mysql_query("select * from products WHERE SOUNDEX(name) > 0 ORDER BY SOUNDEX(name) DESC" ):
```

Here mysql soundex manual [page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex)